# Apply mixer policy to specific services

Tags: istio

I have a mixer policy and adapter that will look for the auth_key in the token I pass, but it applies to all my pods in my default namespace. I need to be able to access two of my pods in the default namespace to login and be granted a header that will allow me to get passed this rule. So can I list the names of the pods I want to apply this rule to instead of it applying to all?

```
# handler for adapter mygrpcadapter
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: handler
metadata:
 name: h1
 namespace: istio-system
spec:
 adapter: mygrpcadapter
 connection:
#   address: "[::]:44225"
   address: "mygrpcadapterservice:44225"
   #address: "35.184.34.117:44225"
 params:
   auth_key: "Bearer"
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: instance
metadata:
 name: icheck
 namespace: istio-system
spec:
 template: authorization
 params:
   subject:
     properties:
       custom_token_header:  request.headers["authorization"]
---

# rule to dispatch to handler h1
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: rule
metadata:
 name: r1
 namespace: istio-system
spec:
 actions:
 - handler: h1.istio-system
   instances:
   - icheck
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Istio Mixer Rules](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/istio.policy.v1beta1/#Rule) have the `match` attribute, you can use it to specify where to apply the rule by matching [Istio Mixer attributes](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/attribute-vocabulary/).

For example, from the Istio documentation:

> match(destination.service.host, "ratings.*) selects any request
>   targeting a service whose name starts with “ratings”

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find it ☺.